# Encode URL and hide confidential information

Tags: php, browser

How do I encode a URL or hide confidential information from being displayed in the browser?

For example, I have the following link:

```
<a href="path/profileId/<?php echo $this->data['profile_id'];?>Edit</a>
```

I don't want `profileId` to be displayed in the browser.

Is there any function or method in Zend or PHP to accomplish this task? I am newbie in Zend so I have no idea if there is even a template which provide such functionality.

Comment: An ID is for identification and not for authentication or authorization.

Comment: @Gumbo yeah i know it ... but in short dun want to display it... this was simple exapmle .. in my case I have lots of parameter to pass.. and its look odd whn it displayed with URl

Comment: Simple then: **don't pass confidential information between pages**. Only pass IDs (real IDs, the kind that are worthless by themselves) and get the real confidential information behind the scenes from a database or session using that ID.

Comment: @Richa: Then what kind of information do you pass, what do you use it for and why do you want it not to be displayed in the URL?

Comment: Richa, your whole approach is wrong. There is nothing bad in passing any required parameters in the url address in general. While there may be some parameters that just no need to pass. If you tell us the whole your task you will get precise answer.

Comment: ok the whole situation is like ... i have a search page in my application ..which have almost 20+ parameters by which user can search any profile ... and when user click on the search button(that is link actually) after filling param. ...then it displays in URL also ..and  according to these param. i have to display another action for user ... i just want to ask is there another way that these param will not display in URL ..but ican access them ????

Comment: Hiding it from the URL is easy: **POST requests**, which in this scenario sounds right. It'll still be in the request itself though (it has to get from the user to server somehow after all), so what you need to clarify is who you want to hide it from and why.

Comment: actually I want to hide this.. because in URL it looks so odd...
and its not imp. for user to show all param..... I just want to serve what they want only .. 
:)

Comment: So this question doesn't actually have anything to do with confidentiality and only with pretty URLs?

Comment: I just wantes to ask ....is it possible to do

Comment: Yes, using POST requests. They don't display the data in the URL, but they're not making it any more *confidential*.

Comment: ok ! but what if all the param are implode with anchor tag's src?
in this case is it possible?


really deceze m so thankful to you that you are listing me patiently

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you will need the ID in some form or another on the `/path/profileId/` page, otherwise you won't know which profile to display, right? If that's the case, it's impossible to completely hide it.
You *could* use a POST request instead of a GET request so the ID won't show up **in the URL**, but it'll still be visible in the HTML and the request body if you know where to look.

The real question is, why is a `profile_id` confidential to begin with? If somebody is able to do something bad just by knowing an *identifier*, your system has a huge problem.

---

You could of cause [encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php) the information before sending it and decrypt it on the receiving end, but that seems pretty nonsensical. The typical way would be to simply pass tokens that are by themselves worthless, but allow you to resolve the real data on the backend. The prime example of this is a [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), another is passing the ID of a record and retrieving the related record, including confidential information, from the database.

Comment: yup :( .. but is there any other method to pass the ID ?
or not showing the contents in URL ? :(

Comment: @Richa If the ID needs to be part of the request, then no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use obfuscation for it. XOR the ID befor echo it out, XOR it back when handling the GET request.

But you should have access controls anyways, is this user allowed to open this link ?

Comment: yah user is allowed to  open this link .. but when the id is pass.. i dun want to display it on browser with URL

Comment: @Richa Why would the id be a password? Unless the user chose an id that is also her password, in which case you can't protect against user stupidity.

Comment: @ deceze this was simple example .. in my case I have lots of parameter to pass.. and its look odd whn it displayed with URl :(

Comment: There are other reasons to obfuscate URLs other than pure confidentiality.  You may want to prevent other applications and services from inferring your API and mining your data.